# Property of set exclusion set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T$ have the property that for all sets $A, B \in T$ we have that $(A\backslash B) \in T$.

How can I prove that $\forall A,B \in T, A\cap B \in T$?

I was thinking I should start with both expressions:
$(A\backslash B) \in T$.

$(B\backslash A) \in T$.

and show that$ (A \cup B)\backslash((A\backslash B)\cup (B \backslash A)=A\cap B \in T$.

I'm not sure how to show that the final part is in that set. It doesn't say anything about unions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: $A\cap B=A\setminus (A\setminus B)$

Comment: Hold that thought.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Comment: I just had to show that these two were equivalent and that did the trick, thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

Write $A\cap B = A\setminus(A\setminus B)$.